# Javascript: Unique Option in Select

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, angularjs

I Want to archive to have unique options in a select.
For example:

At first there is only one `Select`. But you can add infinitely `Selects`. All `Selects` use the same array to fill in the options.

The Array is for example `[1,2]`.
If you know select "1" in the first `Select`, the second `Select` should only have "2" as an option.

Thanks

Comment: So I though of: `select.hasSelected(item) item.removeFromArray();` and `select.undoSelection(item) item.addToArray(); ` But it seems there are no events like this..

Comment: If all use same `Array`, only the first will have any options as you describe it. Or do you mean unique `selected` values?

Comment: What do you mean? There is a foreach loop to create options for every element in the array

Comment: Since you are using angularjs, you can make a custom filter for this, and add selected values to an array, and show only options not in that array.

Comment: ah okay thanks. I will look in this one!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Example of how a filter could look like:

JavaScript

```
app.filter('notInArray', function() {
    return function(inputArray, filterArray) {
        if (inputArray) {
            return inputArray.filter(function (item) {
                return !filterArray || filterArray.indexOf(item) === -1;
            });
        }
        return [];
    }
});
```

Usage:

```
<select data-ng-model="mySelect" data-ng-options="item as item.Name for item in items | notInArray:mySelected">
    <option value="">-- Choose option --</option>
</select>
```

And then maybe have a `$watch` on `mySelect` that adds it to `mySelected`and sets `mySelect` to `null`. This way you only need one `select`. You should probably implement a way to remove options from the `mySelected` `array` also.

Example of this:

JavaScript

```
$scope.$watch("mySelect", function(){
    if($scope.mySelect){
        $scope.mySelected.push($scope.mySelect);
        $scope.mySelect = null;
    }
});

$scope.removeOption = function(option){
    $scope.mySelected.splice($scope.mySelected.indexOf(option), 1);
}
```